# Modify parent element using :contains of child element

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<div>
<a>selected text</a>
<a>text</a>
And more text
</div>
```

Right now I'm getting the `a` with `selected text` with jQuery `:contains`, so I can modify the inner text.

How do I modify the content of the whole `div` based on the presence of the `selected text` anchor tag?

**EDIT:**

I tried something like this: `.parent().replaceWith` but it didn't work. Nothing was replaced.

My jQuery:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a:contains('Thank you for being a CLO subscriber.')").parent().replaceWith($('<span>Thank you for being a CLO subscriber.  You have earned 1 download credits.</span>'));
  });
```

Comment: Please include the jQuery code you use.

Comment: Your code working fine check http://jsfiddle.net/wmwmLh8n/

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bob5hngw/1/ - another option - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bob5hngw/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parent()` or `closest('div')`. Try this:

```
var $parentDiv = $('a:contains("selected text")').parent();
//var $parentDiv = $('a:contains("selected text")').closest('div'); // this works too
```

From there you can use whatever methods you need on the `$parentDiv`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.closest('div')` to target the desired div element.

```
$("a:contains(selected text)").closest('div').replaceWith($('<span>Thank you for being a CLO subscriber.  You have earned 1 download credits.</span>'));
```